# In Java , is it possible to refer static variable of parent class from child class using super keyword?

Tags: java

Whether it is
possible to refer static variable of parent class from child class using super keyword?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  It shouldn't be necessary, since you don't need an instance of the parent class to access a static member, but accessing `super.fieldName` will compile and run just fine.  I hate to complain about a question being too simple, but couldn't you have just run a quick test and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, this is possible in non-static contexts of a subclass. But not in static contexts such as static methods.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the `super.fieldName`. It will compile and run as it should. But it is not necessary to use `super.fieldName` or `ParentClassName.fieldName` to access static members of the Superclass from the Subclass. It can be accessed directly with the `fieldName`.

```
class Parent {
  static int a = 10;
}

class Child extends Parent {
  public void print() {
    System.out.println(super.a); //valid
    System.out.println(Parent.a); //valid
    System.out.println(a); //valid
  }
}
```